# Can /help/privileges/flag-posts be updated to reflect the new flagging reasons?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, help-center

When declining a moderator intervention flag with the 'use standard flags' reason, users are linked to /help/privileges/flag-posts.

The screenshots of the flagging options here still refer to the old flagging options. Users are pointed to use 'should be closed' as an option for flagging questions that should be closed.

This option is no longer present, it's renamed to "Needs improvement".

Can the help center page be updated, so that we link users to the correct flagging guidance when declining their flags?