# What's up with the new way of categorizing flags?

Tags: discussion, flags

*I know this is something that's been implemented a few months ago, but I never had the time to seriously look at it, and actually post something on Meta.*

**I'm completely lost with the way the flags have been categorized**.

Here are the most frustrating things I encounter :

- The flag for "Blatantly off-topic" is located under "Need improvement > A community-specific reason"

  - Not only being *blatantly* off-topic isn't something frowned upon **specifically** on SO, it is also a question that doesn't need improvement. It's completely out of scope, it doesn't belong on SO. One can improve a thousand times a question about the way they should bake their cake, it won't make it.
- The flag "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" is also located under "Need improvement > A community-specific reason"

  - Once again, the question doesn't need improvement, it just needs to be moved elsewhere. It might even be very well formatted, respecting every single guideline for SuperUser, with a MCVE, that deserves to end up in the Hot tab. But it's not supposed to be here.
- The flag "Needs more focus" is at the top-level

  - The guidelines as to know why a question is out of scope is a community-specific matter. Why isn't that flag located under "A community-specific reason" ?
- The flag "Duplicate" exists twice. At the top-level and under "Needs improvement".

As of now, when looking for a specific flag, I'm basically *bruteforcing* every entry to finally find the one that reflects the reason I'm looking for.

I don't know if I got obscenely used to the old way of categorizing the flags, but the new one has been confusing me more than it should. I just **cannot get used to it**.

Am I the only one being confused by this ?

Comment: See here  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346439/282094 and it's duplicate, also:   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346429/282094 asked for an update to the [Flag Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-post).

Comment: If the question belongs on a different site, there's a significant improvement needed - putting it on the correct site and not the wrong ones.

Comment: Questions being insufficiently specific is not a community-specific reason, it's universal on the network because that's the entire intent of the network: specific questions get specific answers so others can use them in the future.